# Xenial Xerus - can see WiFI networks but can't connect

Tags: networking, drivers

I have TP-Link wn8200nd USB adapter, installed Ubuntu 16.04 on my PC together with the previously installed Windows 10.

The problem is I can't connect to the Internet so any solution with downloading from Ubuntu terminal won't help.

Is there any way to download a driver with anther computer and copy the files and is this USB adapter supported?

Comment: Comments have been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41000/discussion-on-question-by-benaya-trabelsi-xenial-xerus-can-see-wifi-networks-b).